# Automatic test input causes end of file error with python

Tags: python, input

I am currently writing a program that is supposed to return certain values when it completes, but the system that tests it is a black box (don't know how it tests the program), and even though I think it would work if I ran the program by itself, the automated tester always raises an end of file error when it encounters the first input prompt.  This the part that is in the main portion of the python code (kind of the first thing that runs).

```
y=list(input("Enter numbers separated by commas and spaces"))
x=list(input("Do the same as above but for other list"))
```

The tester raises the end of file error on the first prompt.  Any idea what may cause that?

Comment: What interface are you running your code in? Web interface, an IDE, terminal, IDLE prompt? Also, a traceback of the error output from python may be very helpful if available.

Comment: It's a web interface.  All the error message has is:  EOFError [line 19] (line 19 is where y=list(input("...")) is).

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: 2.7.6 sandbox is what the tester says.  sandbox meaning virtual machine i assume.

Comment: ok cool, can you try using `raw_input`, changing `list(input(..` to `list(raw_input(..`, what happens?

Comment: Gives the same exact error.

Comment: Ok, if I change the prompt to asking for a single value, it gives the same error.  That seems significant.  Is it possible the program is supposed to be opening a file (but wouldn't the file name need to be known beforehand as well or a prompt needed for that)??

Comment: Perhaps that is what's going on, or maybe it's expecting input by some other means such as `y=sys.stdin.readline().strip()`, maybe try that with each line? Also, have you tried removing the `list(..)` operation and just use`input(..)`?

Comment: I already tried the basic input(...).  I will try your other suggestion, and a few other things I have found as well.

Comment: Says  global name sys is undefined.  So different error, same line.

Comment: I think the test entries themselves are starting and ending with brackets.  Not sure though.  Really a guess.

Comment: I apologize for my incomplete suggestion, at the top before any statements, put `import sys` in order to use `y=sys.stdin.readline().strip()`. If you think the test cases are in brackets `[..]` you can try `for i, val in enumerate(thelist): print i, val`

Comment: Ok, I was off by a lot.  The problem was that the test values, the numbers being tested, were supposed to be defined in the program by ourselves, and then the test would run.  At least that is what it looks like anyway.  If I got the numbers that the tester was using by sheer luck, that is a different story.  Anyway, thanks for helping me work the problem though.

Comment: Sure glad to be of any help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that the tester is not supplying any input at all.  In which case, you (I) have to supply the values in the program itself, not as input but as defined values.